# Unit testing Rails applications' controller's helper Module - How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails

In my rails application there exists a controller helper which is a Module (not a Class) with lot of helper methods defined in it. I wish to write unit test cases for this before I do code refactoring of this module so as to ensure that my understanding of the current system is right and that I have not broken any functionality inadvertantly. We are using RSpec and I would wish to know how would one go about writing unit test cases for the methods of this helper Module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have `app/helpers/address_helper.rb`:

```
module AddressHelper
  def full_address(address)
    "#{address.street} #{address.house_number}/#{address.local_number}"
  end
end
```

You can write spec under `spec/helpers/address_helper_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec/spec_helper' #or something similar, in order to load spec helper

describe AddressHelper do
  describe "#full_address" do
    it "displays the street, local and house number" do
      address = stub('Address', :street => 'Mountain View', :house_number => '7', :local_number => '44')
      helper.full_address(address).should eql('Mountain View 7/44')
    end 
  end
end
```

Key here is `helper` method, which gives you access to helper methods, in this example it is:

```
helper.full_address(address)
```